# "homogenization" of an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hello all of this originated from Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry.

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around projective $n$-space $\mathbb P^n$, its algebraic subsets and their connection to algebraic subsets of affine $n+1$-space $\mathbb A^{n+1}$, via the projection map $\pi : \mathbb A^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb P^n$. For all that I'm missing the link between the respective ideal operations, which should be something like "homogenization" of an ideal.

Also I'm wondering about the connection to the usual homogenization of an ideal $I$ in $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ to an homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$ via homogenization with respect to $x_0$.

Then there's another operation that, in my head, sounds like it should be connected to all that, but maybe its purpose is entirely different. This operation is taking the saturation of an homogeneous ideal $I$ in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$.

We have the following diagram (sorry for the formatting):

{alg. sets in $\mathbb P^n$} $\hspace 1.5cm$ $\longleftrightarrow$ $\hspace 1.5cm$ {cones in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ with $0$ removed} $\subset$ {alg. sets in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$}

$\hspace 1.5cm$ $\downarrow$ $\hspace 7cm$ $\downarrow$

{homog ideals in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$} $\hspace 0.5cm$ $\longleftarrow$ $\hspace 0.5cm$ {ideals in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$}

Here the left-down map is taking the ideal generated by the homogeneous polynomials vanishing on the algebraic set.

The right-down map is taking the ideal of polynomials vanishing on the algebraic set. I do know that the ideal associated to a cone is homogeneous.

The top maps are given by taking the preimage and image of the algebraic sets in $\mathbb P^n$ and $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ respectively.

The cones in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ are by definition the saturated sets in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ with respect to the projection $\pi$, i.e. algebraic sets, that for any point in them contain the whole line through this point and the origin.

Now my main question is, is there a nice map for the lower arrow, so that the diagram commutes? One could go the whole way around, by taking the zero locus of the ideal, then applying $\pi$ to the zero locus and finally taking the homogeneous ideal associated to the obtained algebraic set. But I'm wondering whether there is a simpler way to describe this. This is what i mean by something like "homogenization". 
I.e. what do I do when I only have some not necessarily homogeneous polynomials in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$. Is there a nice way to get an algebraic set in $\mathbb P^n$?

At first I was very happy, because I thought, this was exactly just what is actually called homogenization of an ideal, but "of course" it is not, since that is about taking an ideal from $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ and giving an homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$. This sits in the following diagram:

{alg. sets in $\mathbb P^n = \mathbb A^n \cup \mathbb P^{n-1}$} $\hspace 0.8cm$ $\longleftrightarrow$ $\hspace 1cm$ {alg. sets in $\mathbb A^n$}

$\hspace 1.5cm$ $\uparrow$ $\hspace 7cm$ $\uparrow$

{homog ideals in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$} $\hspace 0.5cm$ $\longleftrightarrow$ $\hspace 0.8cm$ {ideals in $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$}

Here the top arrow from the left to the right is taking intersection with $\mathbb A^n$ and the other direction is taking the topological closure in $\mathbb P^n$.

Both the maps upwards are taking the zero locus of the respective ideals.

The maps at the bottom are homogenization of an ideal with respect to $x_0$ (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousIdeal.html), and in the other direction dehomogenization, by setting $x_0=1$.

My question is, is there any connection between this homogenization and the previous diagram?

Now, as I said, there's another operation called saturation that takes an homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$ and gives an homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$. This is defined by

$\bar I = \{f \in k[x_0, ..., x_n], \exists\ m\ s.t. \forall\ i\ x_i^m s \in I \}$

To be honest I haven't really understood what is happening here and I haven't found much on it, so I don't know whether it is at all connected to the previous stuff. If anyone had some insight on this I would be very thankful. For example I don't know whether the fact that it is called saturation means, that it comes from the saturation with respect to some equivalence relation. I know, that it is needed to get a 1 to 1 correspondence between projective subschemes of $\mathbb P^n$ and homogeneous ideals in $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$, modulo having the same saturation.

I'm very thankful to anyone, who read through this whole text and even more if they can help me.

Btw. this whole problem started, when I tried to write down an equation for a line through two points in $\mathbb P^2$ and realized that I have no clue about what I'm doing.

Comment: My approach would be to find some simple examples of the word "cone" in the upper diagrams top right entry, and see how they behave when you go "all the way around". Maybe you'll get some ideas for what could be a general map or why such a thing wouldn't work!